# Creating nested object in JS under a unique key

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Will probably get downvoted for this but JS is still a new beast to me. I've gotten a data object from the db and would like to have it organized in a JS array object something like this:

```
[ A: [ 
       {"id": 28, "name": "Ackerman, William"},
       {"id": 18, "name": "Anderson, Sherry"},
     ],
  B: [
       {"id": 42, "name": "Barry, Tristan"},
       {"id": 33, "name": "Baker, Lionel"},
     ],
  C: [
       {"id": 79, "name": "Chen, Amy"},
       {"id": 21, "name": "Chen, Benjamin"},
       {"id": 86, "name": "Cornish, Jezebel"}
     ]
    .....
]
```

So I want the unique key to be the letter of the last name and to nest a list of people with the last name within the group. I've only gotten as far as isolating the unique letters but I'm lost when it comes to putting the list of names under each key.

```
var list = [];
for(var i=0; i< employees.length; i++) {
    var key = employees[i].firstletter;
    var obj = {"id": employees[i].employee_id, "name": employees[i].last_name + ', '+ employees[i].first_name};
    var name = [];
    name.push(obj);
    list[key] = name;           
}
```

Of course this only gives me the last result of each group...

Comment: please add the raw data as well.

Comment: The syntax in your first code block is incorrect, fwiw: array notation does not allow for alphanumeric keys; it's just a list of values. If you want alphanumeric keys, what you want is a plain object initializer (`{ }`). Basically, the outer `[ ]` should be `{ }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're recreating the `name` array for every employee. Instead, if there's already an array created for that `key` (employee initial), just reuse it. If there's not, create a new one:

```
var list = [];
for(var i=0; i< employees.length; i++) {
  var key = employees[i].firstletter;
  var obj = {"id": employees[i].employee_id, "name": employees[i].last_name + ', '+ employees[i].first_name};
  var name = list[key] || [];
  name.push(obj);
  list[key] = name;           
}
```

This works because an `undefined` result (what you get with `list[key]` when the `list` object does not contain `key`) is "falsy", so the `name` variable will be assigned an empty array in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an object for grouping and iterate the array with [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

```js
var data = [{ id: 28, firstname: 'William', lastname: 'Ackerman' }, { id: 18, firstname: 'Sherry', lastname: 'Anderson' }, { id: 42, firstname: 'Tristan', lastname: 'Barry' }, { id: 33, firstname: 'Lionel', lastname: 'Baker' }, { id: 79, firstname: 'Amy', lastname: 'Chen' }, { id: 21, firstname: 'Benjamin', lastname: 'Chen' }, { id: 86, firstname: 'Jezebel', lastname: 'Cornish' }],
    grouped = Object.create(null);

data.forEach(function (a) {            
    grouped[a.lastname[0]] = grouped[a.lastname[0]] || [];
    grouped[a.lastname[0]].push({ id: a.id, name: [a.lastname, a.firstname].join(', ') });
});

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```